# docker boto3 AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3

I'm working in a Command line tool using boto3 in a container running python:3.4 image, In my laptop I can run the code without problem but inside the container I receive the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore-1.3.26-py3.4.egg/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore-1.3.26-py3.4.egg/botocore/client.py", line 407, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

I've been trying to find the cause of the problem and I found a possible cause in timezone sync on docker, however I tried by changing the time zone but without any success, this is my Dockerfile:

```
#Docker container image
# Set the base image to use to Ubuntu
FROM python:3.4

MAINTAINER Dave J. Franco <davefranco1987@gmail.com> 

#Update OS
RUN apt-get update 

#testing timezone
ENV TZ=America/Santiago
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

#Project directory
RUN mkdir ufl

#COPY source code
COPY . /ufl

WORKDIR /ufl

#Set permission for ssh keys
RUN chmod 600 -R data/keys

RUN python3 setup.py install

CMD ['ufl']
```

Comment: You should include in the question how you pass your credentials to the code, because the issue could be related to this (maybe, outside the container, you're running with your user, which has credentials on .aws config directory, etc).

Comment: I have tried both with environment variables and by using aws configure, the problem doesn't seems to be credential itself is aws unable to verify it

Answer (score 1):

Check that the server **clock is synchronized**.

If the clock is delayed, can cause this error:

```
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
```

Comment: I have tried by running -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro on the container with no success

Answer (score 0):

well I found a way to solve my problem by mapping the site-packages of python from the host machine into the container

ex:

```
docker run it -v ~/project/.pyenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages \
davejfranco/python
```